# Alertmanager not able send mails via port 465

Tags: smtp, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to send email via alertmanager using credential configured in config.yml file.

I am able to send mail via gmail smtp server using port 587.

But in realtime my customer is using 465 port and I am getting below error

**"first record does not look like a tls handshake"**

Below is my config file

```
route:
 receiver: 'notifications-configuration'
#This receiver name can be any userdefined name
templates:
- '/etc/alertmanager/template/emailnotification.tmpl'

#Send the notifications to below receivers.
#There can be single as well as multiple receivers
#Here there are 2 receivers one is for mail and another is for sending notifications to some API provided
receivers:
  - name: 'notifications-configuration'
    email_configs:
       - from: 'samplemailfrom@gmail.com'
         auth_username: samplemailfrom@gmail.com'
         auth_password: 'fdsfsdfsdfsdssds'
         smarthost: 'smtp.gmail.com:587'
         auth_identity: 'samplemailfrom@gmail.com'
         tls_config:
           insecure_skip_verify: true
         to: 'samplemailto@gmail.com'
```

When I change this smtp host to the the customersmtphost:465 I am getting above mentioned errors

I googled for this issue and Found many links but I am not able to figure it out what change should I do in config.yaml to make it work

Please help on the same.. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR: Port `465` is not supported by the library used in Alertmanager, use port `587`.**

Ports 465 and 587 do different things, per [Google's docs](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en):

> Port for SSL: 465
>
> Port for TLS/STARTTLS: 587

The `SSL` port uses a TLS connection from the get-go, whereas the `STARTTLS` port uses a plain connection that is then upgraded to TLS (see [wiki on STARTTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunistic_TLS).

Alertmanager uses [smtp.Sendmail](https://golang.org/pkg/net/smtp/#SendMail) which states:

> SendMail connects to the server at addr, switches to TLS if possible

This means that only the STARTTLS method is available, it cannot handle plain TLS. **This makes port `465` unusable** with the default Go sendmail package and thus alertmanager. **You must use port `587`**.

Comment: Which means I cant use 465 with alertmanager is my understanding.Thank you so much.

Comment: Indeed. I've made the answer clearer (first line), the rest is just details.